# Этимология слова "доблесть"

Tags: этимология

Как ни пытаюсь, не могу понять, от каких корней происходит слово "доблесть". Или оно не русского происхождения?

Answer (score 6):

Доблесть происходит от добы :
" Доба
ж. млрс. белрск. твер. смол. костр.
пора, час, время, година. Ночной
добой. Он будет в твою добу, в твою
пору, лета. От этого: удобный,
подобный, надобный и пр."  [Даль](http://www.slova.ru/article/6451.html)

Почему же доблесть - храбрость? Проявить доблесть - сделать то, что необходимо именно сейчас, что *надобно* в эту минуту. Не искать путь отступления, а выйти вперед, показать пример действия. Поэтому и труд бывает доблестным : во время войны или чрезвычайного положения - когда очень надо - работать без выходных, в две смены, не щадя своих сил. Вовремя и быстро, *срочно*, без отговорок типа "у меня рука болит" или "вот только штаны подтяну".
*Доблий воин* первый врывался во вражескую крепость.
По-словенски доблесть  - srčnost, а срок - obdobje.

" Доблестное выполнение своих
обязанностей. Т. е. имеет место и в
нашей жизни – доблесть. Мы
привыкли понимать это слово как бы
на войне. Доблестный воин, а вот
человек, который изо дня в день
тащит свою лямку трудовых или
служебных обязанностей, ни на кого не
ропщет, я считаю, что он тоже
доблестно выполняет свои
обязанности." [Размышление о доблести](http://www.hram-sdr.ru/index.php?module=pages&id=111)

Comment: Интересно, у меня сейчас война или чрезвычайное положение?))))))  
А вообще, спасибо за интересный ответ!

Answer (score 5):

*По Семенову А.В*.: ДОБЛЕСТЬ заимствовано из старославянского и означает «героизм», «мужество».
Старославянское – добль (храбрый).

*По словарю  БРОКГАУЗА И ЭФРОНА*: Доблесть - отвага, мужество, геройство.
[Ст.-сл. добль - храбрый, от доба - пора, время. От слова "доба" происходят также "дебелый", "добрый", "удобный".]
Доблестный - отличающийся доблестью; заслуживший славу своими смелыми поступками, мужеством. В современном языке это слово встречается в высоком или официальном стиле речи. Оно может использоваться и иронически, при этом под сомнение ставится и храбрость, и подлинность заслуг.

*По Фасмеру*: до́блесть до́блий, "храбрый, доблестный", ст.-слав. добл̂ь ἀνδρεῖος, γενναῖος (Супр.), словен. dóbǝlj, ж. dóblja "способный, годный".
Связано с до́ба, до́брый; см. Бернекер 1, 205; Траутман, BSW 43; Преобр. 1, 187. Вероятно, следует отделять от дебе́лый; см. М. – Э. 1, 428; Эндзелин, ИОРЯС 15, 1, 215.

Answer (score -1):

Do blest - благословлять (англ.) - следует читать как латиницу без местечкового акцента (до блест), как было начиная с IX века, и понимать, на что благословляет иностранный предводитель войско местных резервистов. Воинов, получивших "do blest", помнят на родине как "доблестных" героев.

Comment: Bread - хлеб (англ.), следует читать как латиницу без местечкового акцента (бред), как было начиная с IX века, и понимать, что за бред ты несешь.